# Unable to clear all data in the SharedPreference and keep only one data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Recently, I made a android app and having trouble with SharedPreference.
What I intend to do is simple. For example, if there are some data for the settings, I want to clear all the datas except for the resolution settings. The following code is only a sample, but it is something that I tried to do. But I'm not sure. The following code works sometimes but clears all the data randomly. Since, I'm new to android. I would want a helping hand. How will I clear all pref and keep only a particular data in the same pref ? And what is the possible cause that deletes all the preference. Some sample will be great! I would love to hear from you !

```
SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("DataSave", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
saveOnlyResolutionInMap(); //Method to save only resolution in List
editor.clear().commit();
reWriteResolutionFromMap(); //rewrites the saved list to pref
editor.apply();
```

Comment: Be sure you have "android:allowBackup="true"" in your manifest

Comment: Actually, I have the allowBackup set to true.

Comment: Could you poste the code for saveOnlyResolutionInMap() and reWriteResolutionFromMap()?

Comment: Actually,  The methods are too long and complicated, therefore, I think that I need some new solution but I have no clue how I can do it.